# kafka: keep track of producer offset

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Apache Kafka *(no confluent)* and have a simple Kafka producer that pulls from a rest API, sends data to Kafka and shuts down.
I had this for testing while I was developing a consumer.

In the consumer I can keep track of the offset, but I don't seem to be able to set a custom offset in my producer.

In my rest calls I would need to keep track of a date so that I don't pull the same data all the time. Am I forced to store that "last timestamp" myself or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your scenario you aren't interested in a "Kafka" offset on the producer side (when you write to Kafka) but an "offset" tracing latest data you pulled from the REST API so you are right you have to do that by yourself.
On the Kafka producer side you are able to know the offset assigned to the latest sent message (inside the RecordMetadata) but it has no relationship with the latest timestamp when you pulled data from the REST API.